# how to return table from ms access switch/iIf statement

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I want to execute a query from inside iif/switch statement in ms access.

like this:

```
switch
  (
   LevelNo = 3, (Select * from ReportBalanceSheetEquityMembers),
   LevelNo = 2, (Select  3 as grpMain, 'Equity' AS MainText, 1 as grpSub, 'Equity' AS subText from ReportBalanceSheetEquityMembers),
   (Select * from ReportBalance)
  )
```

But it always give my this error

```
Invalid SQL statement;expected "Delete, Insert, Procedure, Select, or Update
```

Here LevelNo is my parameter in the query.

How to fix this issue. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: it's a query saved in ms access

Answer (score 0):

you need a select statement from in a query, also you can only return  1 value 
as result if used in query

```
select top 1 switch
  (
   [LevelNo] = 3, (Select top 1 [fieldvalue] from ReportBalanceSheetEquityMembers),........

  ) from msysobjects
```

use in module like (use saved query instead of table)

```
Private Sub Command6_Click()
inp = InputBox("Enter value for LevelNo")
LevelNo = Val(inp)
Dim sql As String
 sql = Switch(LevelNo = 3, "ReportBalanceSheetEquityMembers", LevelNo = 2, _
 "ReportBalanceSheetEquityMembers", _
 True, "ReportBalance")
'DoCmd.OpenQuery sql
DoCmd.OpenTable sql
End Sub
```

Comment: i didn't worked. I have got an error "You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query's FROM clause. Revise the SELECT statement of the subquery to request only one field"

Comment: try it to use in module

Comment: how to use query in module?

Comment: Thanks for the effort. but the problem is I am not calling it from code behind, I have to call it from crystal report.